# AutoFill a Range of Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a quote form - I need to take certain (Header) info and paste into a Master file column `A1:H1`, and then take the quoted items and also paste in to the master file, Column `I1:T1` and `I2:T2` and so on if more than the one item.

I can do most of it but if the quote items are more than 1, then I need to autofill the header information from column `A1:H1` to last column populated in `I?:H?`

Below is what I have written but I can't make it work. It is probably a simple issue that I cant see, or I may be trying to do this a way that would be easier with another loop.

Can anyone suggest a solution to populate the header information in columns `A:H` for as many rows as there were items?

```
Sub TransferQuoteToMasterQuoteTest()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long

    R = 16

    Range("I5:I9").Copy
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "MySheet"
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("K5").Copy
    Sheets("MySheet").Select
    Range("F1").PasteSpecial
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("K11:K12").Copy
    Sheets("MySheet").Select
    Range("G1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Range("I1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B16").Select

        Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R))
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R & ":M" & R).Copy Worksheets("MySheet").Range("I" & (R - 15) & ":T" & (R - 15))
            R = R + 1
        Loop

    Worksheets("MySheet").Select

        LastRow = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row
            With Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A1")
            .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:H" & LastRow&)
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used '&' after 'LastRow' variable please remove it and try below code :

With Worksheets("MySheet")
    .Range("A1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:H" & LastRow)
End With

Comment: Please could you add code tags to your post. Think you are missing a dot too.

Comment: Thanks SJR, I have tried and I still get a Run Time Error `1004`

Comment: Sorry "AutoFill method of range class failed

Answer (score 0):

Subbed down your code by removing Selects and I think fixed your error

```
Sub TransferQuoteToMasterQuoteTest()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long

R = 16
Worksheets.Add.Name = "MySheet"

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I5:I9").Copy
Sheets("MySheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Sheets("Sheet1").Range ("K5")
Sheets("MySheet").Range("F1").PasteSpecial
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K11:K12").Copy
Sheets("MySheet").Range("G1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R))
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R & ":M" & R).Copy Worksheets("MySheet").Range("I" & (R - 15) & ":T" & (R - 15))
    R = R + 1
Loop

LastRow = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row
With Worksheets("MySheet")
    .Range("A1:H1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:H" & LastRow)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SJR, but I still get an error message "Run Time Error 1004" Autofill method of Range Class Failed.

Comment: Try it now, have made a small change.

Comment: Thanks SJR, It now works, I appreciate all your time and help.

Comment: Perhaps you could indicate that this has answered your question.

Comment: Hi SJR, Re your last post "Perhaps you could indicate that this has answered your question" If you read my post from the day before you would see I did indicate you had answered my question.  "Thanks SJR, It now works, I appreciate all your time and help

Comment: Yes ok, actually I meant the formal SO way of indicating that an answer was approved (not sure how to do it as have never asked a question).